# How to log SQL query of the collection?

Tags: magento-1, collection, sql, log

I want to log the SQL query for a custom collection. I tried the following code. But did not work. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
Mage::log($collection->getSelect(),null,'test.log',true);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want the SQL query from a collection you need to cast it as string.
Just add `(string)` to your previously written logging code.

```
Mage::log((string)$collection->getSelect(),null,'test.log',true);
```

Answer (score 12):

Try out `$Collection->printLogQuery(true);` this will print collection query.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code prints the query to the interface.

Answer (score 2):

As Flyingmana explained to me, thanks to him.

```
$collection->load($printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
```

It is important to log or print the query after the loading, because in the `beforeLoad` method can lot of thing be done. So the first answer:

```
Mage::log((string)$collection->getSelect(),null,'test.log',true);
```

should be used AFTER `load` is called.

Comment: How to get current event and print into the logfile in Magento 1.9

Comment: I don't get the question. What event?

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:**

```
$result_colletion = print_r($collection->getSelect());
Mage::log($$result_colletion, null, custom_collection.log,true);
```

**Step 2:** After that Login into  Magento admin section and enable to log setting . Please see below .

**System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings**

**Step 3:** After that see the log file “custom_collection.log” in  var/log/ folder .

Answer (score 1):

```
Mage::log($collection->getSelect()->__toString(), Zend_Log::DEBUG, 'test.log', true);
```

---

Edit:

Instead of using `null` (fallback to `DEBUG`) as second parameter better use one of these from `Zend_Log`:

```
const EMERG   = 0;  // Emergency: system is unusable
const ALERT   = 1;  // Alert: action must be taken immediately
const CRIT    = 2;  // Critical: critical conditions
const ERR     = 3;  // Error: error conditions
const WARN    = 4;  // Warning: warning conditions
const NOTICE  = 5;  // Notice: normal but significant condition
const INFO    = 6;  // Informational: informational messages
const DEBUG   = 7;  // Debug: debug messages
```